# When does the Yeti Zombie appear in Plants vs Zombies?

Tags: plants-vs-zombies

I am yet to see the Yeti Zombie in Plants vs Zombies (PC/iPhone) and I've been playing for 50hrs+.

Is there a specific condition that needs to be filled for him to show, a way to trigger his arrival or is it completely random?

Comment: hehehe 'YET to see the YETi'...

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You need to have completed the adventure mode once. And then in level 4-10 it will appear. If you kill it, then it will randomly appear throughout the game. [(source)](http://plantsvszombies.wikia.com/wiki/Zombie_Yeti)

Comment: Awesome! I shall try and get him to appear tonight :)

Comment: Correct, he appeared in 4-10 for me when I replayed the game. After his initial appearance, you will see him in other levels as well as in the side-games.

Comment: 4-10 what? is this daytime, nightime, pool, or roof? This isn't helpful.

Comment: @jacen.garriss If memory serves, the '4' is area number. So you have 'lawn','gravestones' (night), 'pool' and 'fog' (night).

Answer (score 1):

You play to the end, then when you get to the bit when Crazy Dave chooses the seeds for you, in the fog bit where it is all black, and you can only see when the lightning strikes, the Yeti Zombie comes on there.